# Unix Shell Script to backup a file

Tags: bash, shell, unix

i am new to shell scripting, i am trying to backup a file "main.sh" to "main.sh.bak" using a shell script. If the file exists perform the copy, else display a message. below is the script i am trying, i need to help in the "if" condition to check if the file exists or not in the current directory.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "enter the file name"
read FILE
if [ -f $FILE ]; then
    cp $FILE $FILE.bak
    echo "file successfully backed up"
else
    echo "file does not exists"
    exit 1
fi

exit 0
```

Comment: Try [reading the `test` (or `[`) manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/test.1.html).

Answer (score 2):

The `test` command (`[ xxx ]` is the same as `test xxx`) for an existing regular file looks like:

```
if [ -f $FILE ]; then
  <do something>
else
  <do something>
fi
```

Important note: `-f` is for *regular files*, that is, for instance, not symbolic links or directories. So, if your *files* can be something else than regular files, type `man test` to know more about all `test` options and adapt to your specific case.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. could you help me with some articles / Websites from where i could learn / get practical examples of Shell scripts. Apparently, learning shell scripting and implementing it is what matters. Hence certain practical examples would be useful.

Comment: I frequently recommend this bash beginners' guide: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/index.html. It is probably not the most up to date but I find it well written.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if is a file exists with this sentence:

```
if [ -e $ FILE ]
```

Usign condition with `[ ]` are the same than command `test` there are more options to checks files, for instance:

```
 -b FILE
          FILE exists and is block special
 -d FILE
          FILE exists and is a directory
 -f FILE
          FILE exists and is a regular file
```

And much more, please execute `man test` to see all options

Answer (score 0):

There is also an error in your script. You are missing an semicolon after the `if` statement.

So

```
if [ $FILE ] then
```

Should become:

```
if [ $FILE ]; then
```

Answer (score -1):

```
echo -n "enter file name : "
read file
if [ -e $path/main.sh ]; then
cp /path/main.sh /path/main.bak
echo "Successfully back up"
else
echo "failed"
fi
exit 0;
```

Comment: Please add short explanation to your answer for future visitors.